# Steps to integrate AWS Cognito with both google and custom login with React

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, amazon-cognito

Hi Can anyone let me know the steps to integrate AWS cognito for both custom (username/password) and google sign in ? i am able to get the custom login working without issue.  I was able to configure the user pool with out any issue. I am just wandering about the client side changes.

I use amazon-cognito-identity-js and aws-sdk packages.

Following is some code snippet i use. here i have use a parameter to decide the authenticator. 
It would be great if any of you can provide any feedback . Thank you.

```html
export function getAwsCredentials(userToken, type) {
  let authenticator = '';
  

  if (type == 'CUSTOM') {
    authenticator = `cognito-idp.${config.cognito
      .REGION}.amazonaws.com/${config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID}`;
  }
  else if (type == 'GOOGLE') {
    authenticator = 'accounts.google.com';
  }

  AWS.config.update({ region: config.cognito.REGION });

  AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    Logins: {
      [authenticator]: userToken

    }
  });

  return AWS.config.credentials.getPromise();
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me.  Are you wondering how to get a `userToken` from Google?  Or are you getting a Google token that Cognito doesn't like?  Is it safe to assume you have a Federated Identity Pool already set up, in addition to your User Pool?

Comment: Yes I have set up a federated identity pool . So when the token comes , Can I just add it as a login ? Any idea how to determine how  an  user is logged in (from google or custom ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to your federated identity pool, you can indeed treat all tokens alike.  You only have to change the `[authenticator]` in the logins map.

Presumably, the code that calls your `getAwsCredentials` function would know where the token came from, and it can pass in a parameter, as you're doing above.

I wanted to mention that I don't think this is necessarily a terrible approach.  I might pass in the `[authenticator]` value directly, in place of a `type`, but that's a relatively minor thing.  My major point is that it *might be fine* to leave the responsibility for knowing where the token came from with the calling code, rather than your called function.

**Determining the identity provider using token**

There are, of course, equally valid approaches that might want or need to pull the identity provider out of the token itself.

When you [integrate with Google directly](https://developers.google.com/identity/), you get a token from Google, which you then pass to Cognito (as in your code above).  If you decode the token, you will find

```
"iss": "accounts.google.com",
```

in there somewhere.

Likewise, when you integrate with your user pool directly, the token that you get from your user pool (which you later provide to the identity pool) contains something like:

```
"iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
```

This way you can tell how a user logged in by inspecting their token.

**Note on Cognito Hosted UI**

If you use Cognito's hosted UI to login with Google, you will get an `access_token` and an `id_token` back from Cognito (via redirect).  In this scenario, *all* tokens are coming from the *same* place (Cognito), which means that you can't rely on any calling code to know who the real identity provider is.

In this case, you do have to crack the tokens open if your application cares who the IDP is.  This portion of the `id_token` is what you're probably after:

```
  "identities": [
    {
      "userId": "100000000000000000000",
      "providerName": "Google",
      "providerType": "Google",
      "issuer": null,
      "primary": "true",
      "dateCreated": "1507749926267"
    }
  ],
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1509303233,
  "name": "Your User",
  "exp": 1509306833,
  "iat": 1509303233,
  "email": "youruser@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Thank you Mike !  I will check on your point. I am not using the Cognito's hosted UI